# Extender Provider failed to return an Extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

We upgraded from .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5.  A co-worker of mine is getting the following dialog when attempting to run the ASP .NET web project under the debugger in Visual Studio 2008.  He can build fine, but he can't debug (hence, it's a run-time issue):

Microsoft Visual Studio

"The Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object.  Please correct before proceeding.  (You might rename the current web.config and add a new one.)"

OK

Searching on this error provided one hit that is in French, but Google translated, and the dude deleted his web.config.  Well, my co-worker has a web.config.

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem when i right click on a solution folder Add>View. I got around it by clicking New Item instead.

Comment: Having this error in 2019. Also occasionally get "there is an error in your web.config".

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I encountered the

```
The Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object.
```

message in a winforms designer window.

I'm aware that your question is about ASP.Net 3.5, but in my case I resolved it by:

- Closing the solution in Visual Studio
- Deleting the obj and bin directories from the problematic project.

When I reopened the solution the error no longer occurred in the designer.

**UPDATE:**

VS 2019, resolution still relevant

**UPDATE:**

VS 2022, resolution **still** relevant

Comment: Sounds good.  Thanks for taking the time to answer this question.

Comment: Had the same problem with VS2012 today; this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem when Sharepoint list definitions are shown as normal folders instead of sharepoint list definitions! Thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: I got the error in VS2015, for a WPF project.  I tried to "Clean" the project, but that also did not work.  Then I closed the solution (as Dan suggested), and after reopening I was able to Clean and then Run my project.

Comment: Same here for VS 2015 with a web project. Clean did not solve the problem, but closing VS and deleting the obj and bin folders worked.

Comment: This occured to me when deleting language-specific *.resx files from a Form. The solution above worked.

Comment: Restarting the visual studio alone resolves the issues for me. Thanks.

Comment: I recently saw this in VS 2019 and was able to solve it by closing VS, deleting the .vs folder, then re-opening the solution.

Comment: Worked me for me on vs2017 on a solution with two web projects

Comment: Worked for me as well, asp.net project  in vs2019

Comment: Just to add to the order of operations that worked: I deleted the bin and obj directories in the Web service project to no avail then closed and re-opened Visual Studio 2019 and the error disappeared!  I encountered this one last when I switched branches to merge in some changes from another branch and then switched back to that branch to run the solution again.

Comment: I got the error in vs2022.

Comment: Nice, VS2019, worked.

Comment: as I have special items added to 'bin/debug' and 'bin/release', I didn't delete the 'bin' directory, but believe that just wiping the 'obj' directory was enough.  Thanks.  But yes not sure 'bin' is needed.

Answer (score 35):

I solved it by just closing Visual Studio and opening it again. I was using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and didn't have to delete those folders.

**UPDATE:**

Helps with Visual Studio 2022 as well.

Comment: Same here, using VS Professional 2019 and was seeing that error while upgrading an MVC project from v4.5.2 to v4.8. Restart solved it.

Comment: This did the trick for me in Visual Studio 2022. Thanks.

Comment: Works here as well in 2022. I wonder when they will fix it.

Comment: In that case It's Not a Bug, It's a Feature :)

Answer (score 7):

In my case run Visual Studio as administrator helped. My project uses local IIS and Studio needs Admin permissions to manage IIS.

Comment: This was the solution for me too, for Visual Studio 2019, none of the others worked.  Of course the new VS install didn't carry over the "Run as Administrator" setting on my VS2017 shortcut (which I had set years ago and totally forgotten about)

Answer (score 6):

None of the solutions above worked in VS2019 for me. What did work was deleting the `ProjectName.csproj.user` file and then reloading the project.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2019 I had several webservices in a solution failing to load with this error. In my case the error was caused because I had changed the port numbers in IIS for those web services meaning the  port numbers in .csproj and/or csproj.user did not match IIS. As soon as I updated the .csproj port numbers to match IIS, the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

VS2019 - restarting Visual Studio did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in Visual Studio 2015, the error kept persisting even after cleaning the project, restarting visual studio and restarting my pc.

What resolved it for me, was right-clicking the xaml file and choosing Open with... > XML Editor. It opened the file and the error didn't occur after that.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because a project used IIS and HTTPS,   there was no https binding on the IIS,  adding a HTTPS binding on the default website fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue on the new branch checkout in VS 2019. I just did some changes in web.config and then did undo. it's weird but worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well in my case, I did following

1. cleaned solution
2. rebuilt solution
3. Just opened Web.config in the editor

Launch the application and it worked for me.

Project type: ASP.Net MVC
Framework: .Net Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Interestingly, step 3 solved my problem. I had tried other steps without success.

Answer (score 0):

In VSTO, you can't use the designer while debugging another VSTO app.

For example, if another VSTO debugging session is running and you try to invoke the Excel Designer on a different project, you'll get "The Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object".   Stop debugging to free up the Designer.

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the solutions above worked. I am using VS 2019. In my case, the repository had special characters in the name, so when cloned, the root folder had escaped characters in the name. The compiler could no longer match the file names. Updating the parent folder name and reopening VS fixed the issue.

The detailed error behind 'Extender Provider failed to return an Extender' was related to the inability to find the compiler targets in the path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had deleted 'SSL' from the VS2017 C# project properties debug configuration build tab Conditional compilation symbols.  Putting it back resolved the error.  Apparently SSL require in Debug configuration (but not release).

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem right now, and got help from this thread. It seems its related to web.config being formatted differently from what Visual Studio expects. It might be due to editing web.config on a mac, because when I opened web.config, it detected line breaks that were non-windows, and suggested to replace those. When with CRLF linefeeds. When i said yes to this and saved, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to upgrade the .Net framework 4.7.2 to 4.8 and Restarting Visual studio worked for me.

Comment: There must be some detailed information, and proper steps should have mentioned to solve the issue, this make no sense!