# The Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object. Error when loading project

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2019

I get the following error:

> Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object

When trying to load a WCF project for .Net v4.7.2. I have tried the solutions offered here: [Extender Provider failed to return an Extender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397779/extender-provider-failed-to-return-an-extender/7072526), but with no luck.

This is happening in Visual Studio 2019 v 16.1.6

Any ideas where I should be looking to resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397779/extender-provider-failed-to-return-an-extender/7072526

Comment: Similar issue. Check link above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extender Provider failed to return an Extender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397779/extender-provider-failed-to-return-an-extender)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, i restarted the Visual studio. Then i did clean solution and ran the solution.