# How to fix error Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object when open any report in VS 2019?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I installed VS 2019 and opened my project which is built before with VS 2015
I can open the project and run it without any errors but the error appeared when I try to open any report when double click the report this error show up

```
 The Extender Provider failed to return an Extender for this object
```

I tried the solutions in this question but the error still show and not solved

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397779/extender-provider-failed-to-return-an-extender/7072526
```

I tried these solutions but still show the error :

1- Closing the solution in Visual Studio

2- Deleting the obj and bin directories from the problematic project.

3- run Visual Studio as administrator

4- Clean the project close and open again

5- deleting ProjectName.csproj.user file and then reloading the project.

6- I have 64 bit runtime and installed 32 runtime

7- I removed old reference for crystal reports version 13.0.2000.0 and added new references for VS 2019 version 13.0.4000.0

Also I tried to add new crystal report its added to the project but cannot open it show same error

I need your help please to solve this issue
thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstall crystal reports and crystal report runtime .
Confirm the crystal report version for VS 2019 it must be of version SP 25 and above
After uninstall install crystal report SP 30 and crystal report runtime 64-bit , which is compatible with VS 2019.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working now I found 2 crystal reports runtime 32 bit and 64 bit installed when I uninstall both and install only 64 bit with SP 30 its working :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I discovered ,by comparing previous backup, that the culprit is a hidden folder called  .vs

Here you will find various files - haven't had time to ascertain which one(s) cause(s) the issue but deleting the .vs folder solved the problem. You need to exit the project to delete the folder.
When restarting the project the folder gets rebuilt.